# Delete a sub string given a NSRange

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Given a String and a Range is there any easy method to get a substring by removing the characters from String which come in the passed Range?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should also do the trick:

```
NSString *result = [baseString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 4):

You could get the substring to the start of the range, and the substring from the end of the range, and concatenate them together.

```
NSString* stringByRemovingRange(NSString* theString, NSRange theRange) {
  NSString* part1 = [theString substringToIndex:theRange.location];
  NSString* part2 = [theString substringFromIndex:theRange.location+theRange.length];
  return [part1 stringByAppendingString:part2];
}
```

You could also turn it into an NSMutableString, and use [the `-deleteCharactersInRange:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/deleteCharactersInRange%3a) which does this exactly.

```
NSString* stringByRemovingRange(NSString* theString, NSRange theRange) {
  NSMutableString* mstr = [theString mutableCopy];
  [mstr deleteCharactersInRange:theRange];
  return [mstr autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use this piece of code:
This looks into a list which has a code: a,b,c,d,...
and if the last code is a d.. it will add the code e.

```
NSString *alphabet = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    NSUInteger i, count = [lead count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Listings * l = [lead objectAtIndex:i];
        NSUInteger location = [alphabet rangeOfString:l.code].location + 1;
        if(!([l.code isEqualToString:@"X"]))
        {
            if(!(location -1 == i))
            {
                NSRange range = {location - 2,1};
                NSString *newCode = [alphabet substringWithRange:range];
                l.code = newCode;

            }
        }
```

Comment: `lead`? `Listings`? Ok, 8 years later and the poster hasn't appeared to be on the site in 7 years... but what is this mess? Neither the code in it nor the description have anything to do with the question that was asked.