# Delete Several Substrings from a String in Objective-C, given Ranges of each Substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

This can be considered a follow-up question to [this question about how to 'Delete a substring given an NSRange'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990792/delete-a-sub-string-given-a-nsrange)

Let's say I have a long string, and I would like to delete a few characters from location 'a', a few from location 'b', a few from location 'c' and so on.

If it were a single location and range, I would have used something like:

```
NSString *result = [baseString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

In this case of several locations and ranges, I can always use a for loop. But that would be inconvenient because I will have to change every other range as well as the string size at every iteration of deleting something.

Is there a simpler way to do this in a single iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete substrings from the end of string to begin. First you delete "c" after "b" and finally "a". In this case you don't need recalculate range of remaining substrings.

Comment: Thanks @Iurie; I was so focused on getting an 'Objective-C solution', that I completely missed the more obvious logical solution. Good thinking!